# linking rather than building in stack/cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

question:

What do I have to do in the .cabal file in order to cause the libraries to link rather than build?

background:

I am trying to get coverage details from the command `stack test --coverage`

when I run this build I get the error message

```
Error: The coverage report for xmonad's test-suite "properties" did not consider any code. One possible cause of this is if your test-suite builds the library code (see stack issue #1008). It may also indicate a bug in stack or the hpc program. Please report this issue if you think your coverage report should have meaningful results.
Only one tix file found in /home/paul/temp/xmonad_coverage/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/09c83ca90bc1875ad3d1b5ea4a2a0c369c6367f3ad989533e627c073ee9962e0/8.0.1/hpc/, so not generating a unified coverage report.
```

on the stack documentation site, https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/coverage/, it says that in order to run coverage I must have :

> 2. These test-suites link against your library, rather than building the
>      library directly. Coverage information is only given for libraries, ignoring
>      the modules which get compiled directly into your executable. A common case
>      where this doesn't happen is when your test-suite and library both have
>      something like hs-source-dirs: src/. In this case, when building your test-
>      suite you may also be compiling your library, instead of just linking against
>      it.

when I look in my .cabal file for the library there is

```
 hs-source-dirs:  src
```

and for test there is.

```
  hs-source-dirs: tests
```

I don't understand the purpose of these and whether these are causing the library to build rather than be linked to.

could this be the reason that `stack test --coverage` is failing? or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I could fix this by doing the following:

```
 stack clean; stack build; stack test --coverage --ghc-options "-fforce-recomp"
```

as described by Michael Sloan at https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1305
his explanation for a similar problem was:

> Looks like what's happening is that the library isn't getting rebuilt, despite 
>   reconfiguring with --ghc-options -fhpc and building the package. As a result, the .tix 
>   file generated by the test only includes coverage info for the test itself

Comment: @mgsloan could you check that my answer is not quoting your GitHub comment out of context - thanks